# Porque o Importer do Wordpress é tão lento a ponto de dar erro?

Tags: wordpress, plugin

Exatamente ... Porque o plugin ***Importador do WordPress*** é tão lento para importar o conteúdo do ***xml*** e porque ele não é atualizado a tempos sendo uma função relativamente ***importante*** do mesmo para geração de conteúdo?

E ... existe uma funcionalidade e/ou plugin que desempenhe o mesmo papel do Importador padrão com mais rapidez e melhor performance na comunidade e/ou repositório de plugins?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A maioria dos problemas relacionados com importação de xml, seja no wordpress ou em qualquer outra aplicação (php ou não), está mais relacionada ao desempenho do servidor.
Muitas vezes as pessoas encontram erros relacionados ao **timeout** para carregar o arquivo. Também pode ser que se encontre problemas ao carregar uma base dados muito grande no xml, e ele trava mesmo. Uma saída para esta situação é **dividir o xml** em vários arquivos - pode ser por período, por exemplo, fazendo um xml para cada ano de conteúdo do site. Na maioria das vezes funciona.
Eu, particularmente, prefiro fazer import dos dados pelo banco de dados. A vantagem do xml é que ele pode importar os arquivos de mídia diretamente do site antigo, caso as urls ainda funcionem.

Sobre o plugin, se vc está falando do WP Importer (https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-importer/changelog/), ele foi atualizado em outubro de 2014 pela última vez.

Uma opção a esse primeiro plugin é o Advanced Importer (https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-advanced-importer) - nunca testei, mas tem ótimas recomendações. talvez possa lhe ser útil. Sua última atualização foi esse mês.